# Electron-edge precompile for node v7.4.0

Tags: electron

I am trying to build electron-edge for node v7.4.0 as it does not working for versions after node v6.5.0. I have tried their github instructions https://github.com/kexplo/electron-edge#building-on-windows but it does not work for me. Can anyone help with that please?

Comment: In what way(s) does it not work? Please add information on this.

Comment: It just says that electron-edge is not pre-compiled for node version 7.4.0 to compile for node version 7.4.0 follow instructions on github page. (https://github.com/kexplo/electron-edge#building-on-windows) I'm not sure how to build it for 7.4.0 because the instructions are not very clear to me.